# django manage.py runserver error Unknown system variable 'innodb_strict_mode'"

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7.14, django 1.11 and mysql 5.7 to my local server and it work fine until i tried to connect in our external mysql 5.1 database and got below error when checking my connection (python manage.py runserver). I suspected because external Mysql is version 5.1. Below is my database setting and error message:

```
default':
    {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
         #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.mysql'),
         #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
         'NAME': 'Mfg',
         'USER': 'arastra',
         'PASSWORD': '',   #no password
         'HOST': 'localhost',
         'PORT': '3356', # Tunnel set-up.




File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 101, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1193, "Unknown system variable 'innodb_strict_mode'")
```

Comment: Even I am facing this issue. Can someone look into this

Comment: you found way to fix this?